# Google Custom Search Engine tracking

Tags: tracking, google-programmable-search-engine

I am having this problem for quite some time now: I have a WordPress website that is using Google's Custom Search Engine. I want to track what people/visitors are searching on in that Google CSE. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I want to track what people/visitors are searching on in that Google CSE. Is that possible and how?***

Yes, it is possible using [Site Search reports in Google Analytics](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2717683):

> - The **Site Search reports in Google Analytics** provide data and metrics on how people use search on your site. If you already have a
>     Google Analytics account (using the same Google Account you use for
>     your search engine), we recommend that you configure these reports
>     directly from the Custom Search control panel. The Site Search reports
>     provide the following data:
>
>   - **Search usage**: What did users search for on your site? Did they refine their searches? Where did they go after searching?
>   - **Trending terms**: What are people searching for?
>   - **Pages**: Which pages on your site have the most search usage?

Follow the instructions here to [Configure Google Analytics Site Search](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2715510&topic=2568899&ctx=topic). For the "query parameters" in step number 6 there, see the last step here: [Install Google Analytics Site Search In 5 Steps](http://www.portent.com/blog/analytics/install_google_analytics_site.htm)

Alternatively, using a front-end search form as covered in [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52187/restrict-googles-custom-search-autocomplete-list) question, you could develop custom tracking suited to your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for this! by the way what is google query parameter? because this is required when I am doing the setup.

Comment: You're welcome! See step number 5 [here](http://www.portent.com/blog/analytics/install_google_analytics_site.htm)

Comment: Hi. I'll check step 5. Accept means checking it right? sorry I am fairly new to this system.

Comment: Yes, no worries. Thanks for feedback - I've updated the answer so others will know what to use for query parameters too. Welcome to the site by the way :-)